# Why Custom Keyboard Extension automatically remove from settings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, keyboard

I have created custom keyboard extension.
It is working properly but when i installed in device sometimes it automatically remove from setting and set default keyboard.

When i published my app to Appstore it work fine but in development it is not working so facing problem in testing.

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: maybe it's a bug and i also have same problem. So far did you find any solution?

Comment: No. When i publish to iTunes Store its works properly.

Comment: ok,and did you face problem like delayed to open

Comment: Delayed to open because of lot of task you perform in ViewDidLoad() on main thread.

Comment: then where should i shift my tasks like access userdefaults for getting images for keyboard themes,colors,strings etc?

Comment: put it on background thread

Comment: if i use: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   
    });   what about this?

Comment: thanks @Nimisha Ranipa. i think it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159368/discussion-between-syed-sadrul-ullah-sahad-and-nimisha-ranipa).